# Como limpar um input quando for clicado?

Tags: javascript, html, front-end

Tenho um formulário e quero que, ao carregar a página, apareça ao mensagem no campo "*insert your name here*" e quando o usuário clicar pra digitar, quero que essa frase suma! É possível ? Como se faz?

Comment: Leia sobre o atributo `placeholder` do HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que a forma mais fácil de fazer isso seria utilizar o atributo `placeholder` do `html`:

```html
Name <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="insert your name here"><br>
```

Quando o usuário começa a digitar, a mensagem em questão desaparece de dentro do campo.

Comment: Muito obrigado! eu tinha feito assim onfocus=" this.value= ' ' "  mas do seu modo ainda ficou melhor!

Comment: Depois só aceita a resposta para a comunidade saber que a sua pergunta foi respondida. Para isso basta clicar no sinal de correto, parecido com um "V" existente ao lado da resposta.